# unable to send mail from powershell

Tags: powershell

Unable to send mail via powershell using gmail. The code checks if the website is access and sends the email.

Allow access to less secure app - turned on, two steps verification-on and app password generated.

error: Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.. See my code below:

```
$recipient = "recipeint email"
$smtpUser = "sender email"
$mysubject = "Daily Checks"
$mailbodyonline = “Good day, The Website is available” 
$mailbodyoffline = “Good day, The Website is not available”
$mailserver = "smtp.gmail.com"


$smtpPassword = "C:\mySriptFile\siteemailpass.txt"

$mypassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $smtpPassword -AsPlainText -Force

$Creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $smtpUser, $mypassword



$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.com')

$HTTP_Request.Timeout=10000;


$progressPreference = 'Continue'


$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode


If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {


Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $smtpUser  -Subject $mysubject -Body $mailbodyonline -Credential $Creds -SmtpServer $mailserver -UseSsl -Port 465 -encoding UTF8
}

Else
{
    Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $smtpUser  -Subject $mysubject -Body $mailbodyoffline -Credential $Creds -SmtpServer $mailserver -UseSsl -Port 465 -encoding UTF8
}


If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) { } 


Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
```

When I change the port from 465 to 587 I get the following error;
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

Any help and advise will be highly appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send mail via `smtp.gmail.com`, you need to do some gmail configuration first.

1. Enable "less secure apps" in the google security control panel (seems like you've already done that).
2. Make sure 2-factor authentication is **disabled**. (I think that is why your code gets the error)
3. Make sure the "Captcha" is disabled.

As aside, you should never use curly 'smart-quotes' `“` and `”` in code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for  your response, I managed to resolve the issue.the code was not able to obtain  the password from the text file, i had to recreate the text file. replaced.

$smtpPassword = "C:\mySriptFile\siteemailpass.txt"

$mypassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $smtpPassword -AsPlainText -Force

$Creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $smtpUser, $mypassword      with $smtpPassword = Get-Content "C:\mySriptFile\siteemailpass.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString

To

$Creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $smtpUser, $smtpPassword

It it working now. Thanks for your quick response